# gemのインストール中の警告文について

Tags: ruby

gemのインストール中に以下の警告文が標準出力されました．

参照先のURLを確認してもRailsがなんたらでよく分かりません．
`config....`を修正するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか

```
HEADS UP! i18n 1.1 changed fallbacks to exclude default locale.
But that may break your application.

Please check your Rails app for 'config.i18n.fallbacks = true'.
If you're using I18n (>= 1.1.0) and Rails (< 5.2.2), this should be
'config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]'.
If not, fallbacks will be broken in your app by I18n 1.1.x.

For more info see:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/releases/tag/v1.1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL; DR

Railsの設定で、 `config.i18n.fallbacks = true` となっている部分を `config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]` に変更してください。

## 解説

参照先のURLに書いてある内容を翻訳すると、以下の通りになります。

> 破壊的変更：フォールバック
>   フォールバックはデフォルトの言語を除外するようになりました。（[#415](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/pull/415) 、 [#413](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/pull/413) と [#338](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/issues/338) を修正するかもしれない）
>   あなたのRailsアプリケーションの次の行を確認してください：
>
> `config.i18n.fallbacks = true`
>   この設定は最新版のI18n（1.1.x以降）では誤りになります。代わりに、次のようにしてください：
>
> `config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]`
>   もし修正しなければ、フォールバックは壊れます。
>   [Release v1.1.0 · ruby-i18n/i18n](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/releases/tag/v1.1.0)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．Railsは使ったこと？とかが無いのですが，Railsの設定とは何でしょうか...??

Comment: 上記の警告文はRails使用時に関するものです。もし使用していない場合、おそらく無視して良いものでしょう。

Comment: わかりました．ありがとうございます．